# How to calculate Weighted Frequency

Tags: dataframe, weighted, weighted-average

I am doing a school project on a dataset. I can not understand one of the specific column of the dataset.

Data is as follows. This is an instance of whole dataset

Question: Define your gender?

Responses

```
                             Unweighted Frequency                Weighted Frequency

      Female                 887                                  49.9                             

      Male                   865                                  50.1

      Missing                15
```

Definition:

Unweighted Frequency: This column contains the number of people who chose a specific response
option or response of interest.

Weighted Frequency: This column contains the percentage of people who chose a specific
response option or response of interest. These percentages are weighted and
represent people of a country

Now, I can not understand how could I find out Weighted Frequency.

I mean if I apply the method: (887+865+15) = 1767

Female: (887/1767) = 0.50198   which is not equal to 49.9 even if I multiply it with 100.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you need to further multiply your answer to 100. So basically you want to calculate: (887/1767)*100. This will probably give you an answer like 50.1 which is similar to the weighted frequency from the above table i.e., 49.9